# Does the Muwatta Maalik contain the story of Aisha getting married to the Prophet as a girl of six or seven years?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, source-identification, authenticity, maliki

in the Maktaba Shamela Muwatta Maalik there is a section called:

> ترجمة رجال الموطأ

and in it, there is a subsection on Aisha RA where it says:

> أم المؤمنين، تزوجها رسول الله صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ بمكة، وهي بنت ست سنين، وبنى بها بالمدينة منصرفة من بدر في شوال سنة اثنين من الهجرة، وهي بنت تسع سنين
>
> The Mother of the believers, the Messenger of Allah married her in Makkah and she was a girl of six years...
> **[ [Shamela Reference: Muwatta Maalik - Yahya](https://shamela.ws/book/28107/4586) ]**

I can't tell if this is a part of the Muwatta itself or if somebody just added it in for some "useful context".

Can anyone clarify if this is what Maalik wrote or if its just an editor being "helpful"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what Malik wrote.

Al-Muwatta' is the part of the Hadith, Athar and fatwa statements of Imam Malik which is related to rulings of fiqh topics. Any reports narrated by imam Malik covering other topics can only be found in other sources.

This part is an appendix of the editors it is a collection of biographies of the individuals or person's Imam Malik quoted or reported from in his narrator chains.

Comment: jazakallah :)))